# How to log in to google using python-requests to retrieve html of logged in page?

Tags: python, cookies

I am trying to create a Python script, where given a `username` and `password`, the script logs into Google and then get the HTML data of a page (e.g. Google home page) when logged in.

My code is not working though and I have no idea why.

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')    # need to do this to be able to write html data to a file

from requests import session

payload = {
    'Email': EMAIL,
    'Passwd': PASSWORD
}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}    # to make Google think that this is a real browser not a python script

with session() as c:

    res1 = c.post('https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password', data=payload, headers=headers)

    res2 = c.get('http://www.google.com/', headers=headers)
    html = res2.text

    f = open("test.html", "w")
    f.write(html)
    f.close()
```

When I go into the `html` file that I've written, it doesn't show that I am signed in because there is a "Sign In" button.

I printed out the cookies and there is an "NID" cookie if I don't user `User-Agent` headers when `get` `http://google.com/`, and when I do use the `User-Agent` headers there is a `GAPS` cookie.

I got the `Email` and `Passwd` from the form of the html of the login page.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: why using request module, while you have google api..

Comment: @KarthikeyanKR does google API let you get html of webpage when a user is logged in e.g. Gmail?